# Run an external program with customized environment/options in current buffer

Tags: environment, prog-mode, inferior-buffer

How can I organize Emacs to run a specific external program with some specific environment/options for the mode or the buffer currently open.

My current solution is to use `setenv` before running the external program, however it seems to change the environment for all the buffers in Emacs.

## Example

To work around a bug in Groovy 3.0.0 (see below) I need to set some java option before running `groovysh`. In terminal, I can do the following:

```bsh
JAVA_OPTS=--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs=ALL-UNNAMED groovysh
```

However, Emacs run `groovysh` thanks to `run-groovy` function from the inf-groovy.el file in groovy package. So I usually run `eval-expression` with:

```lisp
(setenv "JAVA_OPTS" "--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs=ALL-UNNAMED")
```

which solves the problem, the inferior Groovy process is now working.

However, all my other buffers now use this value for this environment variable which is not desirable, since I need some other specific java options for other codes. My current solution is to invoke `setenv` every time I change buffer.

### groovysh 3.0.0 not working with jdk 11.0.6

Open a simple file in groovy mode and try to `run-groovy`

With Groovy 3.0.0 and JDK 11.0.6 installed it raises an error:

```java
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:111)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:129)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite cannot access class jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtFileSystem (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.jrtfs to unnamed module @6d4e5011
```

It took me a while to figure out that it was a problem due to version incompatibility between groovy and java, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9390

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `process-environment`

> List of overridden environment variables for subprocesses to inherit.
>   Each element should be a string of the form ENVVARNAME=VALUE.
>
> Entries in this list take precedence to those in the frame-local
>   environments.  Therefore, let-binding `process-environment` is an easy
>   way to temporarily change the value of an environment variable,
>   irrespective of where it comes from.  To use `process-environment` to
>   remove an environment variable, include only its name in the list,
>   without "=VALUE".
>
> This variable is set to nil when Emacs starts.
>
> **If multiple entries define the same variable, the first one always
>   takes precedence.**
>
> Non-ASCII characters are encoded according to the initial value of
>   `locale-coding-system`, i.e. the elements must normally be decoded for
>   use.
>
> See `setenv` and `getenv`.

Therefore you can tweak your approach like so:

```el
(let ((process-environment process-environment))
  (push "JAVA_OPTS=--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs=ALL-UNNAMED"
        process-environment)
  ;; run groovysh here
  (groovy-load-file (buffer-file-name)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot `process-environment` seems to be the right way to go. To make it work I had to run:
`(let ((process-environment process-environment)) (push "JAVA_OPTS=--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs=ALL-UNNAMED"  process-environment) (groovy-load-file (buffer-file-name)))`